# How to query active record for at least 1 foreign key record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My use case is simple. Here are my models.

```
Auction
===============
id
name
expiration_date

AuctionImage
===============
id
auction_id
image_path
filesize
```

I'd like to get all `Auctions` that have at least 1 `AuctionImage`, and order them by `expiration_date`.

```
class Auction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :auction_images
end

class AuctionImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :auction
end
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
Auctions.joins(:auction_images).group(:id).order(:expiration_date)
```

Comment: did you read this? `I'd like to get all Auctions that have at least 1 AuctionImage`

Comment: Correct if I am wrong but for me the code above will load all `auctions` and `auction_images` grouped by `id` and `ordered by date`. The question says it should display not all `auctions`, but only those whom `auction_images` size is bigger > 1.

Comment: `joins` uses `inner join` right so it should only give you records that have at least 1 associated `auction_images`

Comment: Code above will execute following query: Select auctions.* from auctions join auction_images on auction_images.auction_id = auctions.id group by id. When joining with auction_images, all auctions without images will be filtered, you can check it if you want. The only problem with join is that it will return records multiple time if it has more than one image, then we are grouping it and we are left with list of all auctions with at least one image.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest SQL method is likely to be an EXISTS correlated subquery, in which performance would be independent of the number of child records found.

To achieve this in Rails you'd need to do:

```
Auction.where("exists (select null from auction_images where aution_images.auction_id = auctions.id)").order("auctions.expiration_date desc")
```

If you were only expecting very few images per auction then an outer join based method would work, but it's possible that the need for a group by or distinct would cause a delay in return of the first rows from the query, and increase memory consumption on the database server.

As it is the expiration_date order would slow things anyway unless the optimiser found an index that was beneficial.